# Nullable Type handling in RxJava with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, nullable

When using RxJava2 in Java I have the advantage of `map()` filtering emitted null values automatically. However with nullable types in Kotlin I end up doing something like this:

```
val loadConferencesSingle = service.getConferences()
        .map { it.conferences ?: listOf<Conference>() }
```

The call `service.getConferences()` in this case is a Single emitting a `ConferecesResponse` which looks like

```
data class ConferencesResponse(val conferences: List<Conference?>? = null)
```

So in case the complete emitted list of conferences is null, I ended up using the Elvis operator to emit an empty list instead. Emitting a null in `map` is not possible.

Has anybody a clue, how to handle nullable types better in RxJava with Kotlin? I already like this solution and its terseness, but I've got the feeling that there are even better ways to handle this.

Comment: Hi, I think you need to see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern

Answer (score 8):

`Optional` is a completely valid type for this in Kotlin. *The absence* of a value is *also a result*.  You could create a simple data class and function like so:

```
data class Optional<T>(val value: T?)
fun <T> T?.carry() = Optional(this)
```

Optionally, you could create some simple extension functions to make subsequent operators easier:

```
fun <T, R> Observable<Optional<T>>.mapNullable(mapper: (T?) -> R?) : Observable<Optional<R>>
  = map { mapper(it.value).carry() }

fun <T, R> Observable<Optional<T>>.mapFromNullable(mapper: (T?) -> R) : Observable<R>
  = map { mapper(it.value).carry() }
```

..and so on.

Comment: Why would you prefer introducing a new custom `Optional` type if you already have nullable types in the type system that perfectly cover this case?

Comment: Because the reactive streams don't allow `null` values.

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware of that. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends on what is considered a valid result. Does a lack of `conferences` mean there are none? Then the empty list is an appropriate substitute. If it is not meant to happen then throwing an exception might be the appropriate response.

In addition throwing an exception also works with the elvis operator: `it.conferences ?: throw IllegalStateException("Why is it null?")`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So what I am doing right now is the desired behaviour: if the list of Conferences is null, I do not consider this being an error but as the absence of conferences. So what I am doing right now is actually working, but I felt like there is a better way of handling this.